# Data Table not displaying in Razor Page

Tags: c#, html, forms, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm encountering an issue with my Razor page where the data table isn't displaying any data. Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting and resolving this issue?

The table with the headings show up however the actual data doesn't output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D091S.png)

TRIED:
namespace LibraryApp.Pages
{
public class Admin : PageModel
{

```
    public List<Signup_data> listUsers = new List<Signup_data>();
   public void OnGet()
   { 
        try
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Library;Integrated Security=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM login";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Signup_data data = new Signup_data();
                            data.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            data.firstname = reader.GetString(1);
                            data.lastname = reader.GetString(2);
                            data.email = reader.GetString(3);
                            data.password = reader.GetString(4);

                            listUsers.Add(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
       
   }
}

public class Signup_data
{
    public int id;
    public string firstname;
    public string lastname;
    public string email;
    public string password; 
}
```

}

```
<!-- DATABASE connection -->
<h2>List of Users</h2>
<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='/Data/Create'>New user</a>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
@foreach (var data in Model.listUsers)  
{
    <tr>
        <td>@data.id</td>
        <td>@data.firstname</td>
        <td>@data.lastname</td>
        <td>@data.email</td>
        <td>@data.password</td>

        <!-- Buttons-->
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Data/Edit?id=@data.id">Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="/Data/Delete?id=@data.id">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` and then write code that assumes a particular column order... Your program will fail if you change the columns in your table.

Comment: As an aside... If this is to show a list of users on your website then **showing their passwords** is, in multiple ways, a famously bad idea.  (1) You should never *display* or otherwise *send to anyone* a user's password, partly because (2) you should never *have* the user's password in its original plain text form.

Comment: For the question itself... When you debug, does `listUsers` ever have any records to show?  After all, the code which fetches those records is surrounded by a `try` with an empty `catch` block.  Which is your way of telling the code that, if there's an error, you don't need to know or care about that error.  So *asking us* about that error is... odd.

Comment: @David sorry I'm new to coding but the project is just for university. However after debugging the the table will output without the data which I have implemented in the server explorer so im not sure if its  [string sql = "SELECT * FROM login";] causing the issue

Comment: @Oxhei: Well, that's exactly what an empty `catch` block does.  It leaves you "not sure" because you're *explicitly* ignoring any and all errors that code may be producing.  What happens if you remove the try/catch completely?

Comment: @David it causes an unsuccessful build  "Sorry if I'm not too understanding"

Comment: @Oxhei: If your code *doesn't compile* then that would certainly prevent it from working as expected.  In that case you should examine and correct the compilation error(s).  Presumably the code you already had *did* compile though, correct?  The goal here is for you to start [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) and finding where the problem occurs.  Specifically, find if any of the code in that `try` block is producing an exception.  Then you can stop ignoring that exception and start correcting it.

Comment: Hi @Oxhei, Pls check the response data in Network panel in the browser and share with us.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Trust Server Certificate=True` in `connectionString`  :

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Library;Integrated Security=True;";
```